Jack truck on sloped driveway
2010 Silverado 1500 extended cab
I'm a novice trying to learn about jacking up trucks.
I want to jack up one of the front wheels of the truck so the wheel spins. I tried using a floor jack (on the frame behind the front wheel), but the floor jack wasn't plumb; it was at a slight angle due to the slope of the driveway, which looked unsafe. It looked like the jack might tip over. Additionally, the floor jack's wheels sunk into the asphalt, which didn't look overly safe either.

The driveway drops roughly 1 foot over 20 feet in length. Is there a way to safely jack up the truck on the sloped driveway? For example, I could make a wedge-shaped platform out of plywood with a concrete patio slab on top that the jack could sit on, making the jack level & plumb.
I'm aware that I should use wheel chocks and jack stands and engage the emergency brake when applicable.

If you value life and limb, don't jack up any vehicle on an incline. No matter how safe you try to make it with chocks or wedges, there is no substitute for level ground. Of course if it's an emergency, all bets are off and you do what has to be done. But for routine maintenance, nah, be smart and be safe.

It occurred to me that I could part the truck perpendicular to the driveway. It wouldn’t be as sloped that way.
